# Unable to open file network directory

Tags: php, iis

I have written a PHP code that has to write in a directory that is on the server. **The directory has set permissions for everyone as "Complete control"**.

I'm running **IIS Express on Windows 10**.

If I use a local path, the script works correctly but if I set network path \192.168.1.1, the debug returns "Unable to open file". With an executable program, I can write in that path (\\192.168.1.124\BusinessDir\Asc\out2).

Have you got any suggestions to fix that issue? Have I to change the method that I run IIS or PHP?

I have to tried to run php.exe, iiexpress.exe as administrator but nothing change.

Thank you very much for your help.

This is the code that I use.

```
<?php
define("PROJECT_DIRECTORY", "C:\\xx");
define("SHEET_CSV", "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\outtest\\OUT");
define("SHEET_CSV_COPY", "\\\\192.168.1.124\\BusinessDir\\Asc\\out2\\OUT");


function create_sheets_csv($projectName) {

    $projectPath = PROJECT_DIRECTORY . "\\" . $projectName . "\\" . $projectName . ".rpd";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($projectPath);
    //var_dump($xml->Nests);

    $year = date("Y");
    /*$path = SHEET_CSV . $year . $projectName . ".csv";*/
    $pathCopy = SHEET_CSV_COPY . $year . $projectName . ".csv";
    echo $pathCopy;
    $myfile = fopen($pathCopy, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        foreach ($xml->Nests->Nest as $Nest) {

            $SheetUsed = $Nest->SheetUsed->Used;
            $Thickness = $Nest->SheetUsed->Thickness;
            $SheetX = $Nest->SheetUsed->SheetX;
            $SheetY = $Nest->SheetUsed->SheetY;

            $Thickness = floatval($Thickness) * 10;

            $CodiceArticolo = "L$Thickness/10-$SheetX" . "X" . "$SheetY" . "D";


            $txt = $CodiceArticolo . ";" . "NR" . ";" . $SheetUsed . "\n";

            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        }
    fclose($myfile);
    //copy($path, $pathCopy) or die("Impossibile copiare");
}
?>
```

Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: have you tried using forward slashes (`/`) for the network path?

Comment: @Julien yes, but nothing change...

Comment: could you tell us are you using IIS or IIS express? because both are different things.